# Convert integer to boolean choosing the number of bits

Tags: java, type-conversion, integer, boolean

I am trying to convert an integer value to a boolean value. I want to represent my boolean value with X bits determined in advance.

for example :

> 1 = 01 (If i want to represent it with 2 bits)
>
> 1 = 0001 (If i want to represent it with 4 bits)

I don't know how impose the number of bits. 
Also that is my result when I convert 1 :

> 1 = 1
>
> 2 = 10

this is my method called DecimalToBinary. 
THKS

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
if(no==0){
    for(int i=0; i<variableArray.size(); i++){
        result.append("0"); 
    }
}else{
    while(no>0){
        result.append(no%2);
        no = no/2;
    }
}
return Integer.valueOf(result.reverse().toString());
```

**no** is a integer argument of my method

Comment: In your example `1 = 0001`, how is `0001` a boolean? Can you explain your logic?

Comment: May be I am using wrong words. For me, an boolean value is a bit (1 or 0). But it is true that in programming, boolean is TRUE or FALSE. Sorry

Comment: OK, makes sense. I think Januson's answer does what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Integer.toBinaryString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)). Check length of the result and prepend it with desirable number of zeroes.